# what is the grammar explanation for the following?

Tags: grammar

> You will have to have been a member for at least 5 years.

How can I explain "have to have been" to a student?

Comment: You can't just say 'You have to be a member for five years before you can X"? As you have it, two haves make a whole mess. You can do better than to combine 'will have' with 'have been.'

Answer (score -1):

This is a declarative English sentence of the form

> *Subject Transitive-Verb Direct-Object*

The subject is the second person pronoun you. This could be a person to whom the statement is addressed (or persons, since English doesn't have separate pronouns for the second person plural). Or it could mean anyone, and that usage is called the *second person indeterminate*, meaning "Everyone has to have been a member."

The verb is the future tense of the verb *to have. But the sense isn't predictive, i.e., necessarily connected to future time in same way as the fortuneteller's claim, "You **will** meet a talk, dark handsome man." In the OP, this is a modal use of *will* that carries a mandative aspect, i.e., it gives a rule. It means the same thing as "you must", as when a parent tells a child, "You **will** go to bed without dessert!"

The direct object tells you what thing "you" must have, and that's a five-year period of membership. It is expressed as an infinitive clause of the form

> *Perfect-Infinitive Object*

The  perfect infinitive (signaled by *to have* + past participle of the verb *to be*) carries the aspect of completion. The object here is membership, so the meaning is the completed state of membership over the given time period.

So putting it all together, the meaning is

> It's a rule that the state of membership extend for five years or more.